# Qt client programme

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I wrote a program for client on Qt to receive data from server but it is not receiving data and showing received bytes as zero,following is my program:

//client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>

class Client: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Client(QObject* parent = 0);
  ~Client();
  void start(QString address, quint16 port);
  void send(const char*);
  void receive();
public slots:
  void startTransfer();
private:
  QTcpSocket client;
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

//client.cpp

```
#include "client.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>
#include<QIODevice>

Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
    connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()),
    this, SLOT(startTransfer()));

    //connect(&client, SIGNAL(waitForBytesWritten()),
    //        this, SLOT(receive()));
}

Client::~Client()
{
  client.close();
}

void Client::start(QString address, quint16 port)
{
  QHostAddress addr(address);
  client.connectToHost(addr, port);
}

void Client::startTransfer()
{
  client.write("Connection Established", 22);
}

void Client::send(const char *buffer)
{
    client.write(buffer,sizeof(buffer));
}

void Client::receive()
{
    char temp[1024] = {0};
    int len = client.read(temp,client.bytesAvailable());
    printf("\tData recieved from server :: %s\n",temp);
    printf("\tSize of data received is :: %d\n",client.bytesAvailable());
    printf("\tBytes read is :: %d\n",len);
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "client.h"
//#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Client client;
    client.start("192.168.1.2", 9602);

    char buff[] = "Send operation performed from main";
    client.send(buff);
   // while(1)
    client.receive();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here my program function executes and then stops receiving(may be),when I send any thing from server it doesn't take anything.Any suggestions?
Plz don't be rude if I have done any silly programming mistake because I'm newbie.

Comment: You're not waiting for operations to complete. You're initiating the connection and then sending data before the connection has been established. You're also trying to receive data before the data has been confirmed to have been sent.

Comment: @RobbieE: As I am not very good in coding can you elaborate your answer.I mean can you explain me what changes should I make?

Comment: Follow the advice of @RobbieE and connect a slot to the QTcpSocket's readyRead function. In this slot function, you then read data when it is available, rather than trying to constantly read when nothing is there.

Comment: @Merlin069: I tried using readyread() function in slot,but it is showing error as : QObject::connect: No such slot Client::readyRead() in ..\tcp_new\client.cpp:8

Comment: for the above error declare your receive function in public slot.

Comment: yup....done it already

Comment: @RobbieE,@Merlin069,@Satya: I couldn't find any function for send() function,like I have readyread for receive.

Comment: What I mean is that there are a number of background steps needed to make a connection or sending/receiving data. These are usually handled by the message queue which requires that the event loop be running. You are creating the connection, sending data and then receiving data before your event loop is executed so it's no surprise that you're not receiving data. There are two ways to correct your problem: you can use the blocking functions of QAbstractSocket, or you can connect signals to slots and let the event loop notify you when it's ready to make the next step.

Comment: @RobbieE: I'm connecting signals to slot but I couldn't find any funtion for SIGNAL for send() function.

Comment: There isn't one. Look at the documentation: QTcpSocket inherits from QAbstractStocket, which inherits from QIODevice. Look at the available signals for all of those classes. I think the one you're looking for is QIODevice::bytesWritten(qint64 bytes)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work!!!

Comment: @RobbieE: when I tried byteswritten following error was shown:QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments
        QTcpSocket::bytesWritten(qint64) --> Client::send(const char*)

Comment: That's correct. qint64 and const * are different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting @Merlin069's answer....you should use readyRead in signal's place and your receieve function as slot...it will work.I hope this much easy language is understandable to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using while(1) and inside it write your receive function

Comment: Thanx for reply but i tried that also,but it repeatedly shows recived data is zero.